# Could someone explain the logic behind the for loops in bubble sort?

Tags: for-loop, bubble-sort

So I understand the gist of bubble sort, switching pairs if they're not in the correct order, but what I don't get is the logic behind the limits in the for loops (i.e. `i<array.length;` and `j<array.length-1`. Could someone please explain why they are written that way???

```
int temp = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < (data.length - i); j++) {
        if (data[j - 1] > data[j]) {
            temp = data[j - 1];
            data[j - 1] = data[j];
            data[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you write down a small 4-value array on paper, and then walk through the logic yourself?

Comment: Your implementation doesn't match your description.

Comment: Check the article in Wikipedia, It has a nice animation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort?wprov=sfla1. After the first iteration ends (of 1st `for`), the largest item is at the end, that's why you don't need to compare with it. After 2 iterations the 2 largest are sorted at end, so each time you have to make one less comparison: I.e. the inner for reaches a smaller final index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not at all obvious at first sight but you should note that:

Each time the outer loop completes another element will have "bubbled" its way to the top of the array.

The top part of the array contains the highest elements - this top part grows. Starting with:

3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 4

After one outer loop 9 has bubbled to the top

1 3 1 4 5 2 6 5 4 **9**

After the second run 6 has bubbled to the top

1 1 3 4 2 5 5 4 **6 9**

Each time the outer loop runs the inner loop can finish a little bit earlier as we know that the top part of the array will be sorted.